# Suggested edit that leaves answer in question

Tags: discussion, review-queues, edits, suggested-edits, self-answer

While review suggested edits, I came across [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8661457).  The suggestion (IMO) adequately fixed some grammar issue that made the post easier to understand.  But it also left in a huge section of the question that was basically an answer.  The bolded text even tried to divide the post into a new "Solution" section.  I rejected the edit because I felt it was incomplete, but the suggestion was approved 3:2.

Was this a good reason to reject the edit?  Granted, the best solution would be for the question asker to split out the solution into an actual answer.  But short of that, should I have expected the suggested edit to remove the answer portion of the question?  And should I take matters into my own hands by editing out the answer and posting it as a community wiki answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it's a good edit, even though the suggester failed to split out the self-answer, so rejection is wrong.

You are certainly encouraged to do the obvious improvement here.
Actually, that's a great use-case for "Improve Edit", as the question will get bumped anyway.

Just be sure to open the question in a new tab for adding the answer *before* editing out the self-answer, to make sure it isn't closed or locked, and so you need not backtrack.

Comment: Ah that makes sense.  Will choosing improve edit also keep all the fixes to both the question part and the answer part for easy copying into the community wiki answer?

Comment: Well, you will start from the question as it is after approving the suggestion. If that's what you mean. You certainly need to open the question (best before, to make sure you actually *can* add an answer) to get the "post answer"-box.